# Angular not defined when writing unit tests with mocha

Tags: angularjs, mocha.js

I can't seem to find answer for my problem, I've been stuck for a day and would appreciate any answers. I am trying to write unit tests for my controller and when I write: mocha --recursive ./tests 
I get this error:

> ReferenceError: angular is not defined
>       at C:\wamp64\www\music-sp\ang\genre\genre.controller.js:4:5
>       at Object. (C:\wamp64\www\music-sp\ang\genre\genre.controller.js:34:3)

GenreController.js:

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular.module('app').controller('GenreController', GenreController);

GenreController.$inject = ['$location', 'AuthenticationService', 'FlashService', 'UniversalService', '$scope'];
function GenreController($location, AuthenticationService, FlashService, UniversalService, $scope) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.allgenres = [];

     $scope.currentSong = function(url) {
        $scope.PlayerUrl = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(url + '?enablejsapi=1&modestbranding=1&showinfo=0&controls=0&autoplay=1');
    };


    loadAllGenres();

    $scope.loadArtists = function(genreId){
        UniversalService.UpdateGenreId(genreId);

    }

    function loadAllGenres() {      
        UniversalService.GetAllGenres()
            .then(function (genre) {
                vm.allgenres = genre.Results;

            });
    }

}
```

This is my project file structure image, I am writing tests in test folder

[image]

Comment: Do you run tests in nodejs or in browser via [karma](https://karma-runner.github.io/1.0/index.html)? Any way it seems you didn't include angular.js library itself to your tests, what you have to do. And not just angular.js, you need to include all your app, that you want to test.

Comment: I run them via mocha

Comment: Yeah, okay. But mocha is just a test framework. I think you should read about karma test runner and use it for your tests. Because since you write browser app you better test it in browser.

Comment: Okay,, I'll do that :)